# Get all the index information for a given schema -- db2

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

I am writing a JDBC program to fetch some database meta data information and as part of that I want to query all the indexes that are there in a given schema.
I had a look at some JDBC API and from `DatabaseMetaData` interface, can use methods like    `getTables` to get all the tables for a given schema. I am trying to find something similar (or write using a combination of some API) to get information like all the indexes,views etc on a schema. Is there a way to get it? For ex, for index there is a method - `getIndexInfo` but for each of the table in a schema, I need to call this method. My database is db2.

Comment: Using the interface provided by JDBC: no. You will probably need to query the information schema of DB2 directly if you don't want to iterate over all tables and call `getIndexInfo` for each of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [DB2 Catalog Views](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008443.html) to get the information.

As an example, if you want all of the indexes for a table, you'd use a query like this (I'm assuming you're using DB2 on Linux/Unix/Windows here):

```
SELECT *
FROM SYSCAT.INDEXES
WHERE tabname   = @tablename 
  AND tabschema = @schema
ORDER BY indname
```

Comment: It's not recommended that you use SYSIBM views, because they usually change between the DB2 releases. The documented catalog views are in the SYSCAT schema (to which your link points) -- they are guaranteed to be more stable and backward-compatible.

Comment: Oops. Guess that's me being used to querying DB2 for z/OS (which doesn't even have a SYSCAT schema) catalog views. `:)` I changed it to use the SYSCAT views.

Comment: Thanks .. Syscat is working.. let me try working more using the different offering which Syscat has..

Comment: I am able to make some progress using syscat. However while querying syscat.tabauth in the new schema, I got an error saying my id does not have access to this table. How do I compare the grants given to different users in the 2 schema?

Answer (score 0):

I did the following after trying some approaches
1. Wrote a wrapper around JDBC calls to simplify my work.
2. Queried the syscat schema like

```
select tabname from syscat.TABLES where tabschema = ?
```

1. Wrote some java utilities to compare the 2 sets of results returned by the 2 schema and also did some manual comparison.

If I find a better solution, will post it. Thanks a lot for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Getting data from Syscat schema is not correct. in ZOS environment Syscat may be or may not be present because while installation you have options not to install the Syscat schema. so better use Sysibm schema.